# Making a Sum of a nested array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have 3 level nested array and I would like some help to make the generate the sum of its values.
The array goes like

```
                                    SUM
                                 /       \
                               A          B
                              / \         /\
                        Billed  Route Billed Route
                         /        \      /      \
                       Value     Value  Value    Value
```

How can i make a sum of the Billed and Route fields?

So far I have this code

```
foreach($sum as $client)
            {

                $s = 0;
                foreach($client as $stat_name=>$stat_value)
                {
                    $val = 0;
                    // echo "<br><u><i>";
                    // echo $stat_name;
                    // echo "</u></i><br>";
                    foreach($stat_value as $value)
                    {
                        $val += intval($value);
                    }
                    $sum2[$stat_name] += $val;
                }

            }
```

I receive an undefine index error on the first loop for each new key.

Comment: `if (isset($sum2[$stat_name])) { /* do += */ } else { /* do = */ }`

Comment: You want to sum all billed and route fields or sum the billed fields and then sum the routes fields or what?

Comment: Also, a `print_r` of array would help, as there is a much easier way.

Comment: @bwoebi that was EXACTLY what the problem was. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you defined `$sum2[$stat_name]` as `0` ? If not, you'll get an undefined index error on each iteration of the second `foreach` loop because you're trying to do `+=` on a value that isn't defined.

Also, if you're trying add the values of `Billed` and `Route` then storing them in different parts of an associative array (`$sum2[$stat_name]`) is an extra step. Just add them together in the same key of the array.

Answer (score 0):

If those are the actual keys in your array, then:

```
$route = 0;
$billed = 0;
foreach($yourarray['SUM'] AS $ab => $subarray) {
   $billed += $subarray['Billed']['Value'];
   $route  += $subarray['Routed']['Value'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sum2[$stat_name] += $val;
```

is the same as:

```
$sum2[$stat_name] = $sum2[$stat_name] + $val;
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ undefined the first time you loop
```

To solve that, you should initialize it:

```
$sum2[$stat_name] = isset($sum2[$stat_name]) ? $sum2[$stat_name] : 0;
$sum2[$stat_name] += $val;
```